# Error using OpenID Connect with .NET Core 3.0 ASP.NET Core API service

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, openid-connect

I'm trying to implement OpenID Connect with Azure AD in a .NET Core 3.0 ASP.NET Core API service.

It is an API service only, with no UI, and a separate SPA is used to access the API service.

Per the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#send-the-sign-in-request), I'm sending the sign-in request from my SPA, which, after authentication is being redirected back to the `/signin-oidc` endpoint on my API.

At this point, I get an error:-

```
Error from RemoteAuthentication: "Unable to unprotect the message.State.".
```

The initial request from the SPA looks like this:-

```
tenantId = my Azure AD tenant ID
clientId = my Azure AD application ID
responseType = "id_token"
redirectUri = "http://localhost:12345/signin-oidc"
scope = "openid"
responseMode = "form_post"
state = "12345"
nonce = "67890"

https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={clientId}&response_type={responseType}&redirect_uri={redirectUri}&scope={scope}&response_mode={responseMode}&state={state}&nonce={nonce}
```

And my API startup code looks like this:-

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureAD(o =>
    {
        o.ClientId = "(tenant id)";
        o.TenantId = "(client id)";
        o.Instance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";
    })
    .AddAzureADBearer(o =>
    {
        o.ClientId = "(tenant id)";
        o.TenantId = "(client id)";
        o.Instance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";
    });
```

If I omit the state parameter from the initial request, I get a different error:-

```
Error from RemoteAuthentication: "OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler: message.State is null or empty.".
```

The referenced instructions say that `state` is recommended, not required:-

> A value included in the request that also will be returned in the token response. It can be a string of any content you want. A randomly generated unique value typically is used to prevent cross-site request forgery attacks. The state also is used to encode information about the user's state in the app before the authentication request occurred, such as the page or view the user was on.

However, the errors I'm getting seem to imply that `state` is required, and needs to be specially generated.

I've also tried with the following startup code, and get the same errors:-

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
    .AddCookie()
    .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = "(client id)";
        options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + "(tenant id)";
    });
```

Comment: Did you fixed it? I get the same "Error from RemoteAuthentication: "OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler: message.State is null or empty."."

Answer (score 0):

The problem I think is that you can not send requests directly to /signin-oidc from your SPA application. Because the AddOpenIdConnect(...) handler requires that it is the one who makes the initial request to AzureAd and it that it also who receives the request back to /signin-oidc.

AddOpenIdConnect sets its own state value and passes is to the Identity provider aand it expects to see the same state value later when the browser calls /signin-oidc.

I recently blogged about the state and nonce parameter here:

- [Demystifying OpenID Connect’s State and Nonce Parameters in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/12/13/demystifying-openid-connects-state-and-nonce-parameters-in-asp-net-core/)